# How can I find distinct accountid's with no CEO contact?

Tags: t-sql

I have a contact table which has unique contactid as primary key, but may or may not have multiple records for the same account.  My task is to return a list of accountid's and account_name's that do not have any contact with a CEO designation.

I agree this should be simple, and I freely admit to being dumb, so what I did was create a temp table with all unique accountid's, then flag the ones that did have the CEO job title, then do a select distinct accountid, account_name where flag is null group by, etc., which worked quickly and correctly, but is pretty lame.  I frequently write lame scripts which work great, but are shamefully elementary, namely because that's how I think.

There must a nice, elegant way to do this so maybe I can learn something.  Can someone help out?  Thanks heaps in advance for your help! (p.s. Using SS2014)

Sample data below, in which companies 2,3,5 do not have a CEO:

```
create table contact (
    contactid int,
    accountid int,
    account_name varchar(10),
    designation varchar(5));

insert into contact
values
(1, 100, 'COMPANY1', 'MGR'),
(2, 100, 'COMPANY1', 'MGR'),
(3, 100, 'COMPANY1', 'VP'),
(4, 100, 'COMPANY1', 'CEO'),
(5, 200, 'COMPANY2', 'COO'),
(6, 200, 'COMPANY2', 'CIO'),
(7, 200, 'COMPANY2', 'VP'),
(8, 200, 'COMPANY2', 'VP'),
(9, 300, 'COMPANY3', 'MGR'),
(10, 400, 'COMPANY4', 'MGR'),
(11, 400, 'COMPANY4', 'MGR'),
(12, 400, 'COMPANY4', 'CEO'),
(13, 500, 'COMPANY5', 'VP'),
(14, 500, 'COMPANY5', 'VP'),
(15, 500, 'COMPANY5', 'VP'),
(16, 500, 'COMPANY5', 'VP');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, I usually just go with a self-join where null, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  C.accountid
FROM contact C
LEFT JOIN contact CEO
  ON CEO.accountid = C.accountid
  AND CEO.designation = 'CEO'
WHERE
  CEO.contactid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WITH CEO_IDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT accountID
    FROM contact 
    WHERE designation='CEO'
)
SELECT DISTINCT accountID
FROM contact 
WHERE accountid NOT IN(SELECT x.accountID FROM CEO_IDs AS x)
```

The CTE finds all accountID, which do have a *CEO* and uses this as a negative filter to get all accountIDs, which do not have a *CEO*...

You'd get the same with a sub-select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT accountID
FROM contact 
WHERE accountid NOT IN
   (SELECT x.accountID
    FROM contact AS x
    WHERE x.designation='CEO')
```

Comment: Thanks for the selection of approaches and the explanation!